# How to find a specific tag section in an XML file?

Tags: text-processing, grep, xml

The last few lines of my file `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.Vino.gschema.xml`:

```
<schemalist>
  <schema>
   <!-- some other tags -->

    <key name='notify-on-connect' type='b'>
      <summary>Notify on connect</summary>
      <description>
        If true, show a notification when a user connects to the system.
      </description>
      <default>true</default>
    </key>

    <key name='enabled' type='b'>
      <summary>Enable remote access to the desktop</summary>
      <description>
      If true, allows remote access to the desktop via the RFB
      protocol. Users on remote machines may then connect to the
      desktop using a VNC viewer.
      </description>
      <default>false</default>
    </key>
  </schema>
</schemalist>
```

If I want to `grep` this paragraph:

```
<key name='enabled' type='b'>
  <summary>Enable remote access to the desktop</summary>
  <description>
  If true, allows remote access to the desktop via the RFB
  protocol. Users on remote machines may then connect to the
  desktop using a VNC viewer.
  </description>
  <default>false</default>
</key>
```

How should I use the `grep` command to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have to use `grep` ? If `<key name='enabled' type='b'>` only occur once, it would be easier to use `awk` (or perhaps `sed` or even `bash`). Or - of course something like `python`, `perl`, `php`, ... as in something that supports xml.

Comment: I'd advise against using `grep` for such tasks. `grep` is useful for parsing line-oriented data such as `/etc/passwd`, but it's not useful for parsing structured data like XML, JSON or YAML.

If you want to parse XML, use tools designed for parsing XML (such as what others have posted, `xq`, `xmlstarlet`, `xmllint`, XSL, `LibXML`).

Answer (score 13):

Since your given example is a valid XML file, so I would use `xq` XML parser tool for that which is part of the [`yq` installation package](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/).

```
xq -x --xml-root key '
    .schemalist.schema.key[] | select(."@name" == "enabled")
' infile.xml
```

select the "key" tag if its "@name" attribute was equal to 'enabled'.

from the `xq -h`:

> **--xml-output, -x**
> Transcode jq JSON output back into XML and emit it
> **--xml-root XML_ROOT**
> When transcoding back to XML, envelope the output in an element with this name

Answer (score 8):

Since you are dealing with valid XML, you can use `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/schemalist/schema/key[@name='enabled']" infile.xml
```

This will query (`sel`) the XML document and print a copy `-c` of the XPATH element `/schemalist/schema/key`, where that XML node with attribute `name` set to `enabled` is selected.

Output for your example:

```
<key name="enabled" type="b">
      <summary>Enable remote access to the desktop</summary>
      <description>
      If true, allows remote access to the desktop via the RFB
      protocol. Users on remote machines may then connect to the
      desktop using a VNC viewer.
      </description>
      <default>false</default>
    </key>
```

Answer (score 6):

### To be clear:

This is most likely a job for some tool that understands XML documents, not `grep` or the like. There are good answers on this.

---

Perhaps:

`grep`

Using perl-regexp, and other additions.

```
grep -Pzo "(?s)\N*<key name='enabled'.*<\/key>\n" the_file.xml
```

Or a bit more limited (Is not capturing leading blanks ):

```
grep -zo "<key name='enabled'.*<\/key>."
```

`awk`

```c
awk '
/<key name='\''enabled'\''/ { p=1 }
p { print $0 }
p && /<\/key>/ { exit }
' the_file.xml
```

Or

```c
awk "/<key name='enabled'/,/<\/key>/" the_file.xml
```

`sed`

```
sed -n '/<key name='\''enabled'\''/,/<\/key>/p' the_file.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

If you assume the file contains valid XML, you can use `xmllint` from the package `libxml2-utils` and find the desired XML element using XPath expression:

```
    $ xmllint --xpath "/schemalist/schema/key[@name='enabled' and @type='b']" /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.Vino.gschema.xml 
    <key name="enabled" type="b">
          <summary>Enable remote access to the desktop</summary>
          <description>
          If true, allows remote access to the desktop via the RFB
          protocol. Users on remote machines may then connect to the
          desktop using a VNC viewer.
          </description>
          <default>false</default>
        </key>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to obtain the desired output is to use XSL (eXtensible Stylesheet Language) and `xsltproc` - which is installed by default if you are using the GNOME desktop - to transform the input document into the desired document (the output.)

Here is the stylesheet:

```
$ cat transform.xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method='xml' omit-xml-declaration='yes' />

<xsl:template match="/schemalist/schema/key[@name='enabled']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='text()|@*'/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the output:

```
$ xsltproc transform.xsl input.xml
<key name="enabled" type="b">
      <summary>Enable remote access to the desktop</summary>
      <description>
      If true, allows remote access to the desktop via the RFB
      protocol. Users on remote machines may then connect to the
      desktop using a VNC viewer.
      </description>
      <default>false</default>
    </key>
$
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $filename='/home/emmmcl01/gschema.xml';
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $filename);
foreach my $key ($dom->findnodes('/schemalist/schema/key')) {
  my $desc = $key->findvalue('./description');
  my $nm = $key->findvalue('./@name');

  if ('enabled' eq $nm ) {
   print $key;
  }
}
```

This solution iterates through each key element and when it finds a key having a description whose "named" attribute is equal to "enabled" it prints out the element. The solution leverages a Perl XML parser: XML::LibXML which might have to be installed.